# Translation of "should have"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What are the possible translations of "should have", as in "I should have told you earlier"? What are the differences between **"debería (de)"**, **"debí (de)"**, **"debiera (de)"**, **"debía (de)"**, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### English

Firstly, you should know that "should have" translates as "**deber haber**" and not as "deber de haber". "Deber de" is only used to express probability, and as you are asking for "should have" as in "I should have told you earlier" we cannot use "deber de" because "should have" is not about probability, but "obligation".

You can have a look about this in this topic: [What's the difference between "debe de" y "debe"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/769/whats-the-difference-between-debe-de-y-debe)
or in the DPHD: http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=deber

So, your second question would be about "debería", "debí", "debiera", "debía", without "de" preposition. Let's have a look at them. To have a better understanding of the subtle differences, I'll change the person of the sentence:

> You should have told me.
>
> Deberías habérmelo dicho.

1. "debería"

   "Debería" (condicional simple) states condition, although we rarely say the condition, it's guessed easily from the context. For example:

   > Deberías habérmelo dicho [para que hubiera comprado más comida].
   >
   > Debería haber estudiado más [para aprobar el examen].
2. "debiera"

   "Debiera" (imperfecto de subjuntivo) is polite and modest, a way to express courtesy.

   > Debieras habérmelo dicho antes.

   "Debería" and "debiera" are interchangeable, the latter is formal or (very) respectful.

   > Con los verbos modales querer, poder, deber, saber, el condicional
   >   simple puede ser sustituido por el imperfecto de subjuntivo
   >   http://web.abo.fi/csk/proj/vkk/caminando/5/recordando/condicionalysubjuntivo.htm
3. "debí"

   "Debí" is the pretérito perfecto simple, so it's use would be as you would normally use that tense.

   > Debíste habérmelo dicho *antes*.

   Note that here "antes" fits perfectly with the use of pretérito perfecto simple (aka pretérito indefinido) as the time is already finished.

   The tone of this tense is quite direct, like when one is angry or a mom telling off her child.
4. "debía"

   This use of pretérito imperfecto makes the sentences not so aggressive, like when you are asking something: "quería saber si..." rather than "quiero saber si..."

   > Debías habérmelo dicho.

   So, again, "debí" and "debía" are interchangeable, it's just about the tone.

To sum up, the four of them are interchangeable, and you should use them according to the tone of the context. If you are using the first person like in your example, the differences of the tone are gone because it's quite weird you are trying to be polite with you, but note that you could say "¡debí habértelo dicho antes!" if you want to express that you are mad to you because you forgot to tell your friend and the consequences are quite bad. In normal situations, when using other than the first person, especially the second, you would use options 1 and 4 ("deberías" and "debías") as they are quite neutral and polite. Leave 3 "debiste" in situations when you really want to note something, you are angry or upset. Finally, 2 "debieras" is quite uncommon, and you could use it when you don't want to upset the other person.

---

### Español

En primer lugar, deberías saber que "should have" se traduce como "**deber haber**" y no como "deber de haber". "Deber de" solo se usa para expresar probabilidad, y como preguntas por "should have" como en "I should have told you earlier" no podemos usar "deber de" porque "should have" no indica probabilidad, sino "obligación".

Puedes echar un vistazo sobre esto en esta pregunta: [What's the difference between "debe de" y "debe"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/769/whats-the-difference-between-debe-de-y-debe)
o en el DPHD: http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=deber

Entonces, tu segunda pregunta sería sobre "debería", "debí", "debiera", "debía", sin la preposición "de". Echémosles un vistazo. Para entender mejor los distintos matices cambiaré la persona de la frase:

> You should have told me.
>
> Deberías habérmelo dicho.

1. "debería"

   "Debería" (condicional simple) indica condición, aunque rara vez decimos la condición; se deduce fácilmente por el contexto. Por ejemplo:

   > Deberías habérmelo dicho [para que hubiera comprado más comida].
   >
   > Debería haber estudiado más [para aprobar el examen].
2. "debiera"

   "Debiera" (imperfecto de subjuntivo) es más educado y modesto, una manera de expresar cortesía.

   > Debieras habérmelo dicho antes.

   "Debería" y "debiera" son intercambiables, el último es formal o (muy) respetuoso.

   > Con los verbos modales querer, poder, deber, saber, el condicional
   >   simple puede ser sustituido por el imperfecto de subjuntivo
   >   http://web.abo.fi/csk/proj/vkk/caminando/5/recordando/condicionalysubjuntivo.htm
3. "debí"

   "Debí" es el pretérito perfecto simple, por lo que su uso sería como normalmente usarías ese tiempo.

   > Debíste habérmelo dicho *antes*.

   Date cuenta de que aquí "antes" encaja perfectaente con el uso del pretérito perfecto simple (o pretérito indefinido) porque el tiempo (durante el cual se tenía que haber realizado la acción) ya se ha terminado.

   El tono de este tiempo verbal es bastante directo, como cuando uno está enfadado o un una madre le regaña a su hijo.
4. "debía"

   Este uso del pretérito imperfecto hace que la frase no sea tan agresiva, como cuando preguntas algo: "quería saber si..." en vez de "quiero saber si..."

   > Debías habérmelo dicho.

   Entonces, de nuevo, "debí" y "debía" son intercambiables, tan solo es cuestión del tono.

En resumen, los cuatro son intercambiables, y deberías usarlos según el tono del contexto. Si estás usando la primer persona como en tu ejemplo, las diferencias del tono desaparecen porque es bastante raro intentar ser educando contigo mismo, pero date cuenta de que podrías decir "¡debí habértelo dicho antes!" si quieres expresar que estás enfadado contigo porque se te olvidó decírselo a tu amigo y las consecuencias son algo malas. En situaciones normales, cuando uses algo distinto de la primera persona, especialmente la segunda, usarías más las opciones 1 y 4 ("deberías" y "debías") ya que son bastante educadas y neutras. Deja 3 "debiste" en situaciones donde realmente quieres hacer notar algo, estás enfadado o disgustado. Por último, 2 "debieras" es bastante poco común y lo podrías usar cuando no quieras disgustar al interlocutor.

Comment: Related: http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=42377

Answer (score 11):

`should have` actually translates to `debería haber`.

> I should have told you earlier (Debería haberte dicho antes)

Comment: Si dices "debería haberte dicho antes" en España, y nada más, suena incompleta. Le falta el complemento directo, aunque sea en forma de pronombre. Nadie dice eso. Decimos "debería habérte**lo** dicho antes". Y la frase inglesa también se corresponde con "debería habéroslo dicho antes".

Answer (score 2):

Estrictamente, la traducción de "I should have told you earlier" es "debería habértelo/habéroslo dicho antes", pero las otras tres formas que has escrito ("debí", "debiera" y "debía") también se corresponden con la misma expresión inglesa. No veo gran diferencia entre ellas. En España, "debería" es la más habitual, seguida a pocos metros de "debí" y "debía", y con "debiera" a la cola (suena pedante).

Answer (score 1):

`I should have` always means `debería` without `de`.

In general, without tenses considerations,

Deber + infinitivo: obligación. It can be replaced by "tener que" + infinitivo.

Deber de + infinitivo: posibilidad.

Examples:

> Debo hacer los deberes antes de mañana o el profesor me suspenderá. It
>   can be replaced by the most common "tener que": Tengo que hacer los
>   deberes antes de mañana o el profesor me suspenderá.
>
> No encuentro el móvil, debo de habérmelo dejado en casa. It says
>   indicates that it is quite likely that you left your cell phone in
>   your home, given that you cannot find it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are plain wrong. *Should have* does not mean *debería* but *debería haber*. The English version of *Debo hacer los deberes antes de mañana* would be *I should do my homework by tomorrow* or if you wish *I should have my homework done by tomorrow*, but in this case the function of have is completely different from the OP's example. As Diego Mijelshon explained in the other answer, it literally means, **debería haber** and is always followed by a participle, since *haber* acts as an auxiliary instead of a main verb as in your previous example.

Answer (score 0):

> Should have (Debería haber)
>
> I should have told you earlier (Debería habertelo dicho antes)

"Debería", "debí", "debiera", "debía" are conjugations for the verb "deber" for different tenses.

This is the [conjugation table](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/Esverbs.aspx?v=deber) for the verb "deber" in Spanish: