# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "deber" y "deber de"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, preposiciones

¿Hay diferencia en significado en estas dos afirmaciones? ¿O solamente una es correcta?
De serlo, ¿cuál es su connotación?

> 1. *Debo haber dejado mis llaves en el auto.*
> 2. *Debo **de** haber dejado mis llaves en el auto.*

Comment: Cambié el título por uno que parece reflejar mejor la duda concreta; si no lo compartes, ¡cámbialo! Por cierto, qué bueno verte después de tanto tiempo.

Comment: Uy, de hecho veo que ya se preguntó en inglés hace un tiempo: [What's the difference between “debe de” y “debe”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/769/1674). Si resulta ser la misma duda, la marcamos como duplicada.

Comment: @fedorqui Yo creo que acá es un poco distinto en donde la construcción usa el pasado participio.

Comment: Marco como duplicada. Si consideras que no es conveniente, siéntete libre de editar la pregunta para resaltar las diferencias. Nótese por cierto que marcar como duplicado no es nada malo, sino una simple manera de juntar conocimiento. La pregunta en sí es buena, tal y como atestigua su buen recibimiento por la comunidad. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 6):

No, su significado no es el mismo: *deber* indica obligación, mientras *deber de* indica probabilidad, tal y como comenta el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas:

> [**deber**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=deber).
>
> 2. Funciona como auxiliar en perífrasis de infinitivo que denotan obligación y suposición o probabilidad:
>
> a) ***deber*** + infinitivo. Denota obligación: «*Debo cumplir con mi misión*» (Mendoza Satanás [Col. 2002]). Con este sentido, la norma culta rechaza hoy el uso de la preposición de ante el infinitivo: ❌*«*Debería de haber más sitios donde aparcar sin tener que pagar por ello*» (Mundo [Esp.] 3.4.94).
>
> b) ***deber de*** + infinitivo. Denota probabilidad o suposición: «*No se oye nada de ruido en la casa. Los viejos deben de haber salido*» (Mañas Kronen [Esp. 1994]). No obstante, con este sentido, la lengua culta admite también el uso sin preposición: «*Marianita, su hija, debe tener unos veinte años*» (VLlosa Fiesta [Perú 2000]).

Luego tus frases serían:

> 1. *Debo haber dejado mis llaves en el auto.* --> Tengo la obligación de haber dejado mis llaves en el auto.
> 2. *Debo **de** haber dejado mis llaves en el auto.* --> Probablemente he dejado mis llaves en el auto.

Por contexto, la frase que quieres decir parece ser la 2.ª, luego lo correcto para designar probabilidad sería:

> 2. *Debo **de** haber dejado mis llaves en el auto.*

Comment: Me parece que el enunciado inicial de tu respuesta debería ser a la inversa, ¿no?: *"deber de" indica **probabilidad**, mientras "deber" indica **obligación***.

Comment: En la primera implicancia: *tengo la obligación de haber dejado mis llaves* usas la misma construcción para explicar la construcción dada. :0

Comment: @Gustavson tienes razón, me he tomado la libertad de corregirlo.

Comment: Gracias @CarlosAlejo por editarlo. Efectivamente fue una errata.

Comment: @Ustanak fue una errata. Mira la versión corregida

Answer (score 1):

Por añadir un segundo ejemplo a la respuesta de fedorqui, que me parece muy correcta, a mí me gusta ilustrar la diferencia con estas dos frases:

- Ahí debe haber unas 50 personas.
- Ahí debe de haber unas 50 personas.

La primera frase la diría un director de cine preparando una escena, expresando el número de extras que necesita figurando al fondo de la misma (expresando obligación). La segunda frase la diría yo mismo al ver pasar una pequeña manifestación por la calle (expresando estimación).