# Por qué se usa "debe haber" en lugar de "debe de haber" en este ejemplo de hipótesis?

Tags: gramática

En uno de mis libros de gramática, y [aquí en este stack post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/769/whats-the-difference-between-debe-de-y-debe) se dice reservar "debe" por instancias de dar órdenes u otro ocasión de influencia e instancias de hipótesis usar "debe de". Es esto sólo una sugerencia que a menudo puede pasar por alto sin perder ningún sentido?

> ¿No ves que está muy sola? Tienes que hablarle», le aconsejó ella.
>   «¿Qué quieres que le diga, Blanca? Es como una marciana», masculló él,
>   pero **debe haberlo** pensado mejor, porque ahora en vez de abrumarme con
>   charlas académicas de antropología, como hacía al principio, indaga
>   sobre mi pasado y así, de a poco, vamos hilando ideas y conociéndonos.

I got my answer from the comment about the linked RAE, which currently is broken. The (de) is optional for hypothesis but not vice versa.
For instance the following from the same text could not contain de:

> Estuvimos de acuerdo en que yo **debo practicar**, así es que normalmente
>   tratamos de hablar en castellano, pero pronto empezamos a mezclar los
>   idiomas en la misma frase y acabamos en espánglis.

Comment: The link is not broken; if you wait a few seconds, it redirects you to the actual page.

Comment: Anyway, I've just updated it in the answer to the other question :)

Comment: I copied the content in my answer to [¿Qué diferencia hay entre “deber” y “deber de”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20525/1674)