# “Should” (not must)

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I was taught that *deber* means “should.”  The abomination called Google Translate apparently had the same teachers.

But in reading Spanish laws, I see this word used for things that are **required**, and the [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bu2rLyz%7CBu8i6DA) offers four definitions showing an **obligation** (and two that have no connection with “should”).

What are good words to use for something advisable but **not** mandatory?

Comment: I guess to be super clear about that I'd say "Es recomendable etc."  In informal speech I might also say "Es buena idea etc."

Comment: This is related although not an answer to your question: [What's the difference between “debe de” y “debe”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/769/whats-the-difference-between-debe-de-y-debe)

Comment: Yes, “deber de” is on of the two I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed in English that some words that are used informally to mean one thing don't necessarily have a one-to-one correspondence in the realm of precise legal writing.  I would imagine the situation is similar for precise legal writing in Spanish as well.  So I don't think you should assume that what you see in a legal context will exactly carry over to everyday speech.

Please do continue to take Google Translate with a grain of salt. I suggest you take a look at linguee.com when you want to get a quick panoramic view of equivalences between two languages.

The sphere of words that provide advice, instructions, requirements and reproaches is pretty large in both languages, with lots of overlap and opportunities for confusion and misunderstandings.  Choice and interpretation involve weighing some subtle differences.  When trying to translate in one direction or the other in this particular sphere, the following are particularly true:

**(a)** context is important; and

**(b)** certain patterns have been established, and pattern recognition allows us to communicate with a fairly good rate of success despite so much overlap.

I don't want to write a treatise on all the different permutations and meanings but I will try to give you a little taste, from the informal language world, not the legal world.  I'll write a few illustrative sentences but keep in mind that on both sides, there is often more than one way of expressing the idea.

> 1. Manolito, ya sabes, **debes** quitarte las botas en la entrada y dejarlas en el tapete. | *Manolito, you know **you're supposed to** take your boots off in the entrance and leave them on the mat.*
> 2. Es tarde, **debería** acostarme ya, pero esta pregunta es interesante. | *It's late, I **should** [OR **ought to**] go to bed, but this question is interesting.*
> 3. De veras **hay que** llegar con máximo 15 minutos de retraso, si no, la doctora no los verá, son súper estrictos en este consultorio. | You really **must** [OR **have to**] arrive no more than 15 minutes late, because otherwise, the doctor won't see you.  They're incredibly strict in this medical office.
> 4. Cuando empieza a hervir, **tienes que** bajar la lumbre. | *When it starts to boil, you **have to** turn down the heat.*
>
>    Note: this is a bit stronger than *debes bajar la lumbre* | *you have to turn down the heat.*  Similarly, "Tengo que irme ya" is stronger than "Debo irme ya."
> 5. No me contestaron.  ¿**Debo** llamar otra vez? | There was no answer.  **Should** I try again?
> 6. Es imprescindible entregar algo antes de la medianoche, si no, saco cero en esta tarea. | It's imperative to hand something in by midnight; otherwise, I'll get a zero on this homework.
> 7. ¿Forzosamente tienes que cortarte las uñas aquí? | *Must you cut your fingernails in here?*

Things can get more complicated, e.g. "debería haber incluido este ejemplo" and *debías llamar*.

If things get confusing, the following can be helpful:

> Es obligatorio....
>
> Es recomendable que ...
>
> Sería buena idea ...

*(Note about legal language: As a parent with no legal training, one of my Office for Civil Rights education disability complaints failed because my son's 504 plan used the verb "should" instead of "must" or "will."  I have never forgiven the investigators for failing to understand that the people who sit around the table writing the 504 plan are not lawyers.)*

Comment: Grain of salt?  Keep a _bag_ of salt handy when using Google Translate.  A bushel if the language is not Indo-European.

Comment: @WGroleau - I politely sent OP to a specific alternative *other* than Google Translate.  This site has nothing to do with non Indo-European languages.

Comment: I _am_ OP, and I did see your link.  I didn't say anything bad about linguee, I said Google Translate, which _does_ produce garbage for non-Indo-European languages and which I have seen _reverse_ the meaning of Spanish and Italian.  But I also wasn't looking for a "panoramic view" in asking about one particular word.

Comment: @WGroleau - So you are, sorry!  Well, let's get back to your question and my answer.  Is there anything I can clarify further?

Answer (score 9):

The best and most precise translation for "should" is *debería(s)*, it's important to mention that *debería(s)* and *deber* are actually different.

*Deber* is used and conjugated when something is mandatory, whereas *debería(s)* is a special conjugation of *deber* used only for advice.

The way to conjugate *deber* when something is advisable is:

- I should - Yo debería
- You should -Tú deberías
- He should - Él debería
- She should - Ella debería
- It should - Eso debería
- We should - Nosotros deberíamos
- You (plural) should - Uds. deberían
- They should - Ellos deberían

Comment: It not only answers the question, it shows that a lot of teachers AND a lot of textbooks are wrong.

Comment: They're not necessary wrong, it's just that the explanation of why "debería(s)" is a special conjugation of "deber" is even more complicated that I've explained (sorry for that, i didn't have to much time to answer). However, if you are interested in the more detailed explanation, I can rewrite the answer.

Comment: @walen - I don't think that's needed here, because (a) that's not what OP was asking, and because (b) as Alicia cited, that part has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: @walen: not always.  For a simple question on another site, I was redirected with "already has an answer to your question."  But finding the simple answer to a simple question is not easy when there are _28_ answers, most going FAR "beyond that," and answers contradicting each other all have plenty of upvotes.

Comment: No, I said "another site."  And there seems to be two types.  One has the message that you question is a duplicate, and the other message is "this question has your answer."  The second is what they gave me, and indeed, my answer probably _is_ somewhere in the disaster they pointed me to.  So, I'm just saying that going beyond might generally be a good thing, but it can be carried too far.