# Correct usage of debieras and deberías

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

### Español

¿Cuándo es correcto usar *deberías* o *debieras*? (significado y uso).

---

### English

When is it correct to use *deberías* or *debieras*? (meaning and uses)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Translation of "should have"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/123/translation-of-should-have)

Comment: @JoulSauron one ask for translation of 4 words and the other ask for correct usage, where is the duplicate ?

Comment: I think it's clear there's some overlap between this question and the one @JoulSauron linked to. I think I agree with the OP that they aren't exact duplicates, though. Although if 4 other community members vote to close as duplicate, that will be the deciding factor.

Comment: @user983248 I really thought the answer was clear from that question :)

Answer (score 8):

Ambas dos tienen el mismo significado, expresan una idea que sería recomendable ser ejecutada para obtener una consecuencia.
La base está en la forma condicional "debería". Indica condición, aunque rara vez decimos la condición; ésta se deduce fácilmente por el contexto. Por ejemplo:

> Deberías habérmelo dicho [para que hubiera comprado más comida].
>
> Debería haber estudiado más [para aprobar el examen].

Creo que el significado lo tienes claro, supongo que la duda te surgiría si una de las dos implica algún matiz especial en el siginificado. La respuesta es que no, y los puedes usar indistintamente.
Por lo tanto, lo único que varía es su uso. La diferencia con "debiera" (imperfecto de subjuntivo) es que éste es más educado y modesto, una manera de expresar cortesía. Según esta [fuente](http://web.abo.fi/csk/proj/vkk/caminando/5/recordando/condicionalysubjuntivo.htm):

> Con los verbos modales querer, poder, deber, saber, el condicional
> simple puede ser sustituido por el imperfecto de subjuntivo

Ejemplo:

> Debieras habérmelo dicho antes.

Por tanto, "debería" y "debiera" son intercambiables, aunque el último es formal o (muy) respetuoso.

Comment: si, es asi, aunque no este muy de acuerdo en lo personal jaja

Answer (score 5):

No estan mal las respuestas pero dejenme echar un poco mas de agua para clarificar el tema. O creo que mas bien que agua, gasolina.

En realidad no tienen el mismo significado y tampoco se utilizan indistintamente. El problema es como en todo, en la forma vulgar si se utilizan indistintamente y tienen el mismo significado. Esto sucede porque como bien te ha dicho JoulSauron, generalmente hay una elipsis y no se expresa el subjuntivo.

Pero si usaramos las dos a la vez... ¿Qué sucedería?

Un claro ejemplo es la siguiente frase:

> "Deberías pensar seriamente si debieras decir tales palabras"

Es evidentemente que no prestamos buenas maneras en cambio a:

> "Debieras pensar seriamente si deberías decir tales palabras."

*(En general se expresa: "Deberías pensar seriamente si deberías decir tales palabras" o incluso: "Debes pensar seriamente si debes decir tales palabras".)*

Como verás en primera instancia es importante el rol gramatical que juegan. Uno es el modo subjuntivo (que expresa lo posible, lo probable, pero no real) y el otro es del modo indicativo (aunque algunos consideran el condicional como un modo aparte), que expresa realidad, algo concreto (que sucedió, sucede o sucederá, salvo que esté mintiendo claro está).

Esto obviamente se nota más en ejemplos con el presente, errores tales como:

> "Si llego a ganar, triunfaría"

cuando en realidad es:

> "Si llegase a ganar, triunfaría"

"Debieras decir tales palabras" no es algo real, es algo que la persona pudo haber dicho o no, no lo sabemos. Quiza solo piensa en decirlo y no se anima.

En cambio "deberías pensar" sí es algo cuasi-real. Es un consejo, algo concreto, piensalo en este instante. Es dificil entender el rol gramatical en este caso, y es por lo tanto también que en la economía del lenguaje, en lo cotidiano se mezclan y se confunden.

Seguramente esté aceptado cambiarlos, pero si es una pregunta académica, para sintetizar, la respuesta es:

- Juegan diferente rol en la gramática.
- Juegan diferente rol en la semántica a la hora de "pensar" en que una es una condición, y otro es algo probable pero no real.

¿Importa o alguien nota la diferencia? No.

Comment: Fantástica respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

**Español**

Excelente pregunta. La verdad es que la respuesta requiere una explicación gramatical profunda la cual no soy capaz de dar por lo que acompaño la respuesta con esta [liga](http://www.elcastellano.org/consultas.php?Op=ver&Id=4419).

En resumen ambas palabras se pueden utilizar indistintamente pero es mas comun ver *debieras* en literatura, principalmente en textos antiguos.

**English**

Excellent question. Truth is that the answer requires a deep grammatical explanation which I am incapable of giving so I rather add this [link](http://www.elcastellano.org/consultas.php?Op=ver&Id=4419).

In a nutshell both words can be used interchangeably but is more common to see *debieras* in literature, mainly in older texts.

Comment: In this case, I’d translate *textos antiguos* into *old texts* or perhaps *older texts*. “Ancient” texts would almost be something you expect to find on papyrus rolls. :)