# When the subject is "A y B", which grammatical number does the verb agree with?

Tags: gramática, verbos, conjugación, conjunciones, número-gramatical

Consider the following sentence:

> *A and B are the same.*

The verb here agrees in number with the subject, which is why we use *are* instead of *is*. Does this happen in Spanish too? Which of the following is correct:

> **A y B es lo mismo**
>
> **A y B son lo mismo**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option is the correct one:

> <s>A y B es lo mismo</s>
> **A y B son lo mismo**

From the article about *concordancia* (concord?) in the Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas:

> [**concordancia**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5).
>
> (...)
>
> 2. Reglas generales
>
> a) **La coordinación de dos o más sustantivos o pronombres en singular, siempre que cada uno de ellos se refiera a un ente distinto, forma un grupo que concuerda en plural con el adjetivo o el pronombre, o con el verbo del que son sujeto**: «*Rehogar la cebolla y la zanahoria picadas durante quince minutos*» (Pozuelo/PzPérez Técnicas [Esp. 2001]); «El oxígeno, el hidrógeno y el carbono los proporciona el medio» (LpzTorres Horticultura [Méx. 1994]); «*La sal y el agua son gratis*» (Martínez Evita [Arg. 1995]).

Comment: Glad you answered because my question comes from one of yours (http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17650/es-lo-mismo-un-modismo-y-una-frase-idiomática-y-una-expresión-fija) where you have used **es lo mismo** in a similar construct.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to say it: Bazinga! :-)

Comment: @TheLearner the title there is _¿Es lo mismo un modismo y una frase idiomática? ¿Y una expresión fija?_. I have to admit I am not very sure if it is ok, although it sounds good to me. _Un modismo y una frase son lo mismo_ would be the correct form to answer it. However, when asking it, you can see it as if I am omitting "decir": _¿Es lo mismo [decir] A y B?_ in which case it is fine. I will wait for others to clarify it :)

Comment: @fedorqui as the question is stated, the proper form would be _¿Son lo mismo A y B?_ Your claim would be valid if the question was stated as _¿Es lo mismo [decir] A que [decir] B?_ Note the _que_ instead of _y_.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo OK. When you mean the proper form, does it mean that the way I wrote is directly wrong? Just to clarify, because it does not sound that bad to me :)

Comment: @fedorqui I know, it happens often that something sounds right to us Spanish speakers, but it does not mean it is the gramatically correct way to write it. Remember [that discussion](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2394/12637) about the use of "debiera" instead of "debería". All in all, I think you have written here your own answer when you said that only the second option _A y B son lo mismo_ is correct. Maybe a good question is **why does it sound right to us?**

Comment: @CarlosAlejo splendid answer and splendid comment. Noted and updated the title of the question :)

Comment: @TheLearner so after the interesting discussion here I updated the title. It is funny I was explaining how a thing was, while doing it wrong in another place :O